# US company Warrants issued in Europe

Tags: investing, value-investing, warrants

Can one bank issue another companies warrants ? I have been searching for warrants on US companies and turns out that a lot of these warrants are issued in Euro instead and by different banks rather than the US companies they represent. Any help will be very much appreciated.  is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite common that a bank in country X will issue warrants representing stock of company traded in country Y. People living in the country X wanting to invest in that stock, may not have a direct access to a stock exchange in the country Y, and buying these warrants (while the bank itself buys the actual stocks to cover them) is the only way.

Such a warrant is sometimes called "[Global Depository Receipt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_depository_receipt)".